# Getting the error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, valueerror

I am developing a program that generates music chords for a given MIDI file using evolutionary algorithm.

Here is the code for my fitness function:

```
def get_fitness(solution, average_notes):
total_score = 0
for i in range(len(average_notes)):
    if average_notes[i] == -1:
        continue
    total_score += (average_notes[i] - solution[i]) ** 2
return total_score
```

And this is the code of my selection function:

```
def selection(population, average_notes):
    bracket = np.random.permutation(population)
    new_population = []
    for i in range(0, len(bracket), 2):
        if get_fitness(bracket[i], average_notes) > get_fitness(bracket[i + 1], average_notes):
            new_population.append(bracket[i])
        else:
            new_population.append(bracket[i + 1])
    return new_population
```

I am getting the following error for the if condition in my selection function

```
   ..... at: if get_fitness(bracket[i], average_notes) > get_fitness(bracket[i + 1], average_notes)
 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have researched how to solve this error and I found some solutions about to avoid using **and** because it implicitly calls **bool**. I also found some other solutions online but they were not enough to solve the error I have in my code.

Comment: I think we'll need to see the `get_fitness` function

Comment: And double check that the error is coming from the `if get_fitness(bracket[i], average_notes) > get_fitness(bracket[i + 1], average_notes):` line.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: When you do `average_notes[i] == -1`, is `average_notes[i]` an array, or a single number?